# How to have struct members accessible in different ways

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct, pointer-to-member

I want to have a structure `token` that has start/end pairs for position, sentence, and paragraph information.  I also want the members to be accessible in two different ways: as a start/end pair and individually.  Given:

```
struct token {
  struct start_end {
    int start;
    int end;
  };

  start_end pos;
  start_end sent;
  start_end para;

  typedef start_end token::*start_end_ptr;
};
```

I can write a function, say `distance()`, that computes the distance between any of the three `start`/`end` pairs like:

```
int distance( token const &i, token const &j, token::start_end_ptr mbr ) {
  return (j.*mbr).start - (i.*mbr).end;
}
```

and call it like:

```
  token i, j;
  int d = distance( i, j, &token::pos );
```

that will return the distance of the `pos` pair.  But I can also pass `&token::sent` or `&token::para` and it does what I want.  Hence, the function is flexible.

However, now I also want to write a function, say `max()`, that computes the maximum value of all the `pos.start` or all the `pos.end` or all the `sent.start`, etc.

If I add:

```
  typedef int token::start_end::*int_ptr;
```

I can write the function like:

```
int max( list<token> const &l, token::int_ptr p ) {
  int m = numeric_limits<int>::min();
  for ( list<token>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i ) {
    int n = (*i).pos.*p; // NOT WHAT I WANT: It hard-codes 'pos'
    if ( n > m )
      m = n;
  }
  return m;
}
```

and call it like:

```
  list<token> l;
  l.push_back( i );
  l.push_back( j );
  int m = max( l, &token::start_end::start );
```

However, as indicated in the comment above, I do not want to hard-code `pos`.  I want the flexibility of accessible the `start` or `end` of any of `pos`, `sent`, or `para` that will be passed as a parameter to `max()`.

I've tried several things to get this to work (tried using unions, anonymous unions, etc.) but I can't come up with a data structure that allows the flexibility both ways while having each value stored only once.

Any ideas how to organize the `token` struct so I can have what I want?

---

## Attempt at clarification

Given struct of pairs of integers, I want to be able to "slice" the data in two distinct ways:

1. By passing a pointer-to-member of a particular start/end pair so that the called function operates on any pair without knowing which pair.  The caller decides which pair.
2. By passing a pointer-to-member of a particular `int` (i.e., only *one* `int` of any pair) so that the called function operates on any `int` without knowing either which `int` or which pair said `int` is from.  The caller decides which `int` of which pair.

Another example for the latter would be to sum, say, all `para.end` or all `sent.start`.

Also, and importantly: for #2 above, I'd ideally like to pass only a single pointer-to-member to reduce the burden on the caller.  Hence, me trying to figure something out using unions.

For #2, the struct would be optimally laid out like:

```
struct token2 {
  int pos_start;
  int pos_end;
  int sent_start;
  int sent_end;
  int para_start;
  int para_end;
};
```

The trick is to have `token` and `token2` overlaid somehow with a `union`, but it's not apparent if/how that can be done and yet satisfy the accessible requirements.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking...can you clarify why you can't use std::string with iterators marking positions? With iterators you don't need to use write the distance functions, there are stl algorithms built in that let you compute the distance between iterators.

Comment: Could you please try restating the problem you are trying to solve in simple terms?  I think there are many here that can help you but it is difficult to understand what it is exactly you are trying to do.  For instance, what is a "position"?  Is this is in a text string?  Are the start/end pairs indexes into a string?  Thanks, Mike.

Comment: I think he's looking for a way to pass in a functor that pulls out the member.

Comment: @Chris H: What does std::string have to do with this?  Regardless, the distance function is just a trivial example for the purposes of asking a question here.  The real functions will be more complicated.

Comment: @mikelong: What a position is is irrelevant.  Forget that I called them pos, sent, and para.  Call them A, B, and C: three pairs of integers.  Also forget that I called them start and end: call them X and Y.

Comment: @Stephen: no, I don't want a functor.

Answer (score 2):

Just a try.

```
int max( list<token> const &l,                                                  
         token::int_ptr p,                                                      
         token::start_end_ptr mbr ) {                                           
  int m = numeric_limits<int>::min();                                           
  for ( list<token>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i ) {        
    int n = ((*i).*mbr).*p;             
    if ( n > m )                                                                
      m = n;                                                                    
  }                                                                             
  return m;                                                                     
}
```

Comment: Well, yes, this works, but, according to my clarification above, an initially unstated goal (sorry) was to be able to do this by passing only a single pointer-to-member.

Comment: This compiles fine on g++ 4.3.

Answer (score 1):

I'm building upon the answer [baol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562535/how-to-have-struct-members-accessible-in-different-ways/2562777#2562777) gave:

If we add a `token_reference` struct and some global (ick!) variables we can have this:

```
struct token_reference
{
    token::start_end_ptr start_end_ptr;
    token::int_ptr int_ptr;
};

token_reference pos_start =  { &token::pos, &token::start_end::start };
token_reference pos_end =    { &token::pos, &token::start_end::end };
token_reference sent_start = { &token::sent, &token::start_end::start };
token_reference sent_end =   { &token::sent, &token::start_end::end };
token_reference para_start = { &token::para, &token::start_end::start };
token_reference para_end =   { &token::para, &token::start_end::end };

int max( std::list<token> const &l, token_reference& ref ) {
    return max(l,ref.start_end_ptr,ref.int_ptr);
}
```

called like this:

```
tokenList aList;
int value = max(aList,pos_start);
```

you get a function taking a `list` and one more parameter.

Comment: They don't have to be truly global: they can be static data members of token.  That aside, the solution isn't bad.

Comment: But: is there no clever way to do this with unions (anonymous or not) inside the token struct?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `boost::bind` or `boost::lambda` libraries. Or if you can use a compiler with C++0x support you might want to use some of the newer features instead of manually binding the member attributes. And then you can use the algorithms provided in the STL...

Anyway this can possibly do what you want (I did not even take time to try and compile it, so it might as well not compile):

```
int max( list<token> const &l, token::start_end_ptr m, token::int_ptr p ) {
  int m = numeric_limits<int>::min();
  for ( list<token>::const_iterator i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); ++i ) {
    int n = (*i).*m.*p;
    if ( n > m )
      m = n;
  }
  return m;
}
int main() {
   list<token> tks;
   int x = max( tks, &token::pos, &token::start_end::start );
}
```

Note that this is not the path to flexibility well understood: you are binding the algorithm to the types `token`, `token::start_end` and `int`...

C++0x:

```
list <token> tks;
int the_max = 0;
for_each( tks.begin(), tks.end(), 
      [&the_max]( token const & t ) { the_max = max( the_max, t.pos.start ); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
struct start_end {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct pairs {
    struct start_end a;
    struct start_end b;
}
```

so is the idea is to slice the data to operate on X's or Y's dynamically?

```
 int distance(start_end m, start_end n, int member_offset){
     int val_a = *(&m + member_offset);
     int val_b = *(&n + member_offset);
     int distance = val_b - val_a; 
     return distance;
}
```

Comment: Un-nesting the start_end struct doesn't change anything.  Also, the use of the "struct" in "struct start_end a;" is unnecessary: this is C++, not C.

Comment: (1) You don't show how you compute member_offset. (2) In C and C++, adding offsets to pointers scales the pointer by sizeof(T) which T in this case is the start_end struct.  You'd first have to cast &m to pointer-to-char, then add member_offset (which presumably would be measured in bytes).